# Selecting Turkish characters from table?

Tags: mysql, character, turkish

I have a MySQL table that contains texts (nicknames) with Turkish characters in them.
For example, there is a word "**çığır**" in Turkish. ( "cigir" with english characters )
It is stored in the database like "**Ã§Ä±ÄŸÄ±r**". When I print this word in my .php page, it is printed correctly (as "çığır").

But when I do the query

```
SELECT * FROM  users WHERE nickname LIKE 'çığır';
```

it returns an empty set. of course the other way (nickname like Ã§Ä±ÄŸÄ±r) works, but I want do be able to do the first one, too. How can I do this?

p.s.:
I have tried

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8';
SET character_set_connection = 'UTF8';
SET character_set_client = 'UTF8';
SET character_set_results = 'UTF8';
```

these don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try SELECT * FROM  users WHERE nickname LIKE '%çığır%'; that way it will find the word anywhere in the string.

Comment: Where do you do the query from? What collation is the table in?

Comment: I tried the query in both PHPmyAdmin and .php scripts none worked. Collation is utf8_turkish_ci. thanks for all answers. I will try them now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  users WHERE Convert(nickname using utf8) LIKE 'çığır';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off translating the database to UTF-8, making sure php is querying with the right charset,

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $link);
```

and forget about the funny encoding altogether.  This way all your queries will work automatically.